# call to Page method causes page events to fire only when using master page

Tags: asp.net, master-pages, webmethod, page-lifecycle

I'm using asp.net 4.0 with vb.net. I have a page method (static webmethod) in my aspx page, and I use jquery ajax to call it. 
Recently I incorporated a master-page. And my code does not work anymore. 
when debugging I noticed that with master-page, page events fire, but not when my page was stand alone.

Any thoughts on how to avoid page events firing when I call the page method. And Why the page- life-cycle events are fired when we use a master page, even we are calling a static page method?

Thanks

**EDIT:** Here is a short version of my markup

1) MasterPage is realy basic, No code behind, just makup.

2) the ASPX page has changed a little by putting the markup inside ContentPlaceHolders:

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="UserDetail.aspx.vb" Inherits="UIAdaptor.UserDetail" MasterPageFile="~/UserEditor/StaticPages.Master" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
   <%--a couple of JS and CSS were moved to the masterPage--%>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
   <%--Same markup as before using MasterPage--%>
</asp:Content>
```

3) Jquery that calls page method

```
    $.ajax({
    type: "Post",
    url: "../UserDetail.aspx/ValidateUser",
    data: "{'v_strUserName':'" + v_strUserName + "','v_strEmailAddress':'" + v_strEmailAddress + "','v_strGuidCurrentUserID':'" + v_strGuidCurrentUserId + "','v_strAddedRights':'" + v_strAddedRights + "'}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    async: false,
    success: function(data) {...}
    ....
    });
```

4) page method

```
        <WebMethod()> _
    Public Shared Function ValidateUser(ByVal v_strUserName As String, _
                                        ByVal v_strEmailAddress As String, _
                                        ByVal v_strGuidCurrentUserID As String, _
                                        ByVal v_strAddedRights As String) As String
        Dim s As String = WebNavigator_Common.ValidateUser(v_strUserName, _
                                                           v_strEmailAddress, _
                                                           v_strGuidCurrentUserID)

        Dim blnAskMetadataValidation As Boolean = AskMetadataRightGrantingValidation(v_strAddedRights)

        Return s & ";" & blnAskMetadataValidation
    End Function
```

Comment: Are your ASP.NET AJAX Page Methods inside the master page or a content page?

Comment: My page method is inside the content page. I moved it to the master page, but got the same issue. page events are firing.

Comment: AFAIK, ASP.NET AJAX Page Methods will not work when inside of a master page, but obviously should work inside of a content page. When you run the page can you see if there is an error in the console of your browser's developer tools (F12 Tools for IE, Firebug for Firefox or Chrome Developer Tools)?

Comment: There is no error calling the page method itself. the error raises inside PageInit event, because this event handler uses some querystrings that are not sent when calling the page method. That is why firing the page events cycle bugs things. I think I will move the page method to a separate asmx web service page. I dont see any reason why I should keep page method inside my aspx page. But still dont understand Why page events fire only when I use a master page.

Comment: That is very strange indeed, I have used ASP.NET AJAX Page Methods in several projects, all of them using master pages. You might want to post your markup and code-behind just for a sanity check.

Comment: Post the entire jQuery code (including selector) and the markup that comprises this selector.